# Sort Order in People Search Core Results

Tags: 2010, user-profile, people-search

I wish to display a list of new users on my SharePoint site. I've picked the People Search Core Results webpart and have a user list, but how do I order it by creation date?

Iknow in Active Directory (where I sync my users from) there is a `whenCreated` attribute, but is there anything similar in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following post:
http://consultingblogs.emc.com/paulgalvin/archive/2008/03/10/walk-through-use-people-search-for-department-contacts.aspx

So basically, you can sort the results in the XSLT itself. By default it's sorted based on "preferredname":

```
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
      <xsl:for-each select="All_Results/Result">
        <xsl:sort select="preferredname"/>
        <!-- Emit <tr> and <td> tags for the columns you want to show -->
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
```

Just replace the default XSLT with your custom one with the correct user profile property to sort on.

Comment: To add to this, if you have an AD attribute you can map it to a User Profile Property, create a Managed Property mapped to that User Profile Property and then use the name of the Managed Property for the sort above :)

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried it but just something you could check out for -

You could change the XSLT of the Core results web part. Can you try adding something like this? -

```
 <xsl:sort select="created by" order="ascending" />
```

OR

Check this [post from msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/senthilkumarmani/archive/2010/06/05/custom-core-results-web-part-in-grid-format-with-context-menus-amp-sorting-filtering.aspx) where sorting and filtering is implemented by **custom** core results web part. You might be able to develop something similar for People search core results too.